# Socks with numbers that should be different then days of the week

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $14$ socks, on each sock there is a number. the numbers on the socks are 
$\{1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7\}$
Each day $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ Alis pulls on two socks (and throw them to the laundry at the end of the day).

How many options there are if both:
A) no $2$ socks with same number.
B) no day and sock with the same number.

If there is just $3$ days and $3$ pairs of socks, then there is $1$ option.
If there is just $4$ days and $4$ pairs of socks, then there is $9$ option.
If there is just $5$ days and $5$ pairs of socks, then there is $216$ option.

Comment: Is this two questions, for condition (A) and for condition (B) separately, or just one, where both conditions apply?

Comment: It is 1 question, where both conditions apply

Comment: OK, thanks. Then I commend Brian M Scott's answer and have nothing to add to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can represent each possibility by an $n\times n$ binary matrix. The rows correspond to the days of the week, and the columns correspond to the numbers on the socks. Condition (A) means that we must have two $1$s in each row, and condition (B) means that no $1$ can be on the main diagonal. We use up all of the socks, so there must be two $1$s in each column as well. Conversely, every matrix with two $1$s in each row and each column, none of them on the main diagonal, corresponds to a legitimate possibility.

If $a_n$ is the number of possibilities, the sequence $\langle a_n:n\ge 3\rangle$ is the tail of [OEIS A007107](https://oeis.org/A007107) starting at $n=3$, as may be seen from the COMMENTS entry. Two formulas are given, one exact but *very* ugly, and one asymptotic:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{s=0}^k\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}(-1)^{k+j-s}\frac{n!(n-k)!(2n-k-2j-s)!}{s!(k-s)!(n-k-j)!^2j!2^{2n-2k-j}}\;,$$

and

$$a_n\sim 2\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\frac{n^{2n+\frac12}}{e^{2n+\frac52}}\;.$$

The next few values after that $a_3,a_4$, and $a_5$ that you already have are $a_6=7570$, $a_7=357\,435$, $a_8=22\,040\,361$, $a_9=1\,721\,632\,024$, and $a_{10}=166\,261\,966\,956$.

Comment: Nice translation and OEIS find

Comment: @Joffan: Thanks. I’m constantly being surprised by just how much there is in OEIS. I’ve been giving them a little money every year for some time now; seems only fair, considering how much I use them!